# Which regimen of the AstraZeneca vaccine was approved (in UK and India respectively)?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

The Oxford-AstraZeneca made furore two months ago for a dosage error in its 3rd phase trial. The 3000 or so trial participant who got the regimen with the erroneous dosage, showed apparent greater resistance to covid-19, in terms of the contrast of the number of acquired infections in the vaccinated group vs. those in the control group. I believe the company announced shortly after that it would start a larger follow-up 3rd phase trial to investigate the efficacy and safety of this apparently superior regimen. Since I didn't hear any news regarding publication or announcement of results of this follow-up trial, I was wondering whether the regulators in the UK and/or India have approved the initial "1 dose + 1 dose" regimen or the alternative "1/2 dose + 1 dose" regimen (or both)?

Comment: Apparently, the regimen with 2 full doses got approved: https://www.bbc.com/news/health-55280671 If someone could write an answer with a link e.g. to official MRHA documents this can yield a quick and easy answer with a handsome reputation reward.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/government/news/oxford-universityastrazeneca-covid-19-vaccine-approved

Comment: You know you can answer you own question, right?